# Debugging IIS hosted .NET application

Tags: .net, debugging, iis

I have published an hosted a .NET application in IIS, is there any way I can see what happens in the code when I make a call to the server side from my Android client?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the debug - attach to process menu option to attach to w3wp.exe

As long as the compiled code is the same as the source, and the pdb's are there, it should attach fine.

Comment: Can you please explain the steps.

Comment: @Sreekanth in Visual Studio: "Tools" -> "Attach to Process..."; or more simply, set the web debugging options to be IIS, and just hit F5. Note: you need to be running Visual Studio as a local administrator in elevated privilege to debug inside IIS.

Comment: I forgot about the permissions, thanks @MarcGravell - it's probably worth noting that when I use that, it's under the "Debug" -> "Attach to Process..." menu, rather than Tools.

Comment: In that case what should I use as the URL? I have given the project URL as "http://localhost/WcfImageUpload" 
I understand the localhost should be replaced with 10.0.2.2, but should I need to provide a port number?

Comment: @Sreekanth anything that resolves to that site in IIS

Comment: Not if you're hosting on Port 80, no. VS will, by default, create an application under whatever website is hosted on Port 80 which in your case will be "WcfImageUpload"

Comment: I have given the project url as http: //localhost/WcfImageUpload in the debug option in the settings,The question is that how should I refer the URL from the android client so that I can debug?

Comment: @Sreekanth Sorry, I misunderstood. You should be able to point the android client at http://pc-name/WcfImageUpload or http://ip-address/WcfImageUpload

Comment: Why? Normally When I host in the IIS as the localhost/... I used to use the ip address 10.0.2.2 because that is the address that is used from the android instead of the localhost. My question is will I need to use a port number?